# Why android animation in my app is not as smooth as goLauncher animations?

Tags: android, animation

I am using animation for item click of GridView.
My animation file is expand_then_contract.xml as below

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.1"
        android:toYScale="1.1" />
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.1"
        android:fromYScale="1.1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />

</set>
```

And I'm applying it in the onItemClickListener of GridView as below

```
onItemClick(... View view ..)
{
Animation expand_contract = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.expand_then_contract);
        view.bringToFront();
        view.clearAnimation();
        view.setAnimation(expand_contract);
        view.startAnimation(expand_contract);
}
```

It is working as expected. But it gets stuck in between. At some point when it is contracting back to normal position, for a moment it freezes. Why does this happen. Why can't animation in my code work as smoothly as they make it in GoLauncher Animations. Do they use any external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with interpolator , your job is done in two diffrent steps

So , Better you merge them both in one step or Use linear interpolator so that there is no halt between executoion